# Hover de um elemento e capturar outra tag

Tags: css

Preciso fazer um hover num parágrafo e trocar a cor da tag link, como consigo fazer isso?

```css
p:hover a {
        color:red;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#">Título</a>
<p>Passar o mouse troca a cor do link acima</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No css não existe um meio de trocar a cor do item anterior apenas trocar a cor dos itens `abaixo` do `dentro` do elemento, sugiro que você troque a ordem dos elementos para que possa usar o marcador `+` do `css`.

O marcado `+` selecione o proximo elemento definido após ele como no exemplo abaixo:

```css
a:hover + p { 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="">hover me</a>
<p> change color<p>
```

*Resumo: Ao ativar o `hover` no elemento `a`, altere a cor do elemento `p` que vier em seguida.*

Todavia você pode fazer isso com `javascript/jquery` usando a função `prev()`:

```
$('p:hover').prev('a').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Nessa ordem - o elemento com `hover` afetar um elemento anterior não é possível, apenas um posterior. Mas como o que importa é a ordem no html, nada impede de você mudar o posicionamento visual via CSS.

```css
p:hover + a {
        color:red;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<p>Passar o mouse troca a cor do link acima</p>
<a href="#">Título</a>
```